# Count amount of entries within one year and other criteria

Tags: excel, date, filter, excel-formula

For my Pilots logbook I am trying to be able to make a easy search where you can enter certain criteria and get the amount of landings and time in flight.

For example you could enter the departing airport and it would give you the amount of takeoffs from that airport.

So far I have been able to get the results using the `COUNTIFS`function.

**Trying to add a field, where you can enter a year and it would only count the occurrences in that year** is giving me a hard time!

The date is in the following format: `dd.mm.yyyy`. The year to search for would be entered in a cell (`yyyy`).

Just adding it to the `COUNTIFS`obviously doesn't work. I know I can get the year out of the date using the `YEAR`function, yet I can't figure out a way of including this into the `COUNTIF`.

Any Ideas?

CODE:

```
=COUNTIFS(Logbook!F3:F2000,IF(ISBLANK(B30),"*",B30),Logbook!C3:C2000,IF(ISBLANK(C30),"*",C30),Logbook!K3:K2000,IF(ISBLANK(D30),"*",D30),Logbook!L3:L2000,IF(ISBLANK(E30),"*",E30),Logbook!G3:G2000,IF(ISBLANK(F30),"*",F30),Logbook!B2:B2000,B30)
```

Where `B30` is the cell with the year, and `B2:B2000` being the cells with the dates.

I also tried to compare by the text (somewhat like `RIGHT(Logbook!B2:B2000,4)=B30`) but it doesn't do anything but returning a #VALUE error.

Comment: I think a `PivotTable` is the way to go for the count and for the time in flight.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I am hoping there is another way to do it!

Comment: Why would you hope for another way?  A pivot table will be quicker, easier and more robust that any formula-based solution.

Comment: Haha I guess part of it is masochism, the other part of me wants to gain knowledge on how to do stuff like that, and I gotta be honest, I know like nothing about PivotTables, so I was hoping for a way around... But I'll definitely give them a shot, now that you are all telling me to use them! :D Thanks !

Comment: give a more detailed explanation of your references to the cells and I will let your know what formula you can use. It would be better if you could give a screenshot of a sample data, and your expected results column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a really good case for PivotTables and slicers... You could even avoid the `RIGHT()` formula if you format the dates; then you could use the built-in `group` feature of PivotTables.

[image: Table]
[image: Pivot]
[image: Slicer]